# Generate missing part of 3D mesh

Tags: image, image-processing, 3d, bioinformatics, mesh

Below is a mesh of a damaged skull. I want to take the 3D mesh of the damaged area in order to 3D print an implant for the skull.

[image]

I was thinking of mirroring the skull and then subtracting the original from the mirrored skull(since any skull is symmetric). I could not find a proper software to do mirroring and subtracting. I tried using slicer and paraview.

I greatly appreciate if you can help me in suggesting a method and software to extract the missing area of the skull.

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to import the existing data into  [OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/index.html) and do my (re)constructive solid geometry there.

Comment: Thnaks for your help sir, but i finally got a solution using mimcs, which is much superior for this particular situation